# Como passar lista de um picklist (bootstrap) via POST (ajax)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Bom dia, não sei como passar os dados deste componente para meu `controller` java.

Veja imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo, eu tenho estes campos que passo por requisição `POST` ao meu `controller` e funcionam OK, chega até o `controller` java:

```
BoxApp.controller("CadastroCertificadoController", function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.clientes = {};

    $scope.iniciar = function() {
        $http.get('/boxmlV2/cadastrocertificado').success(function(response) {
            $scope.clientes = response;
        });
    };

    $scope.iniciar();
    $scope.clientes2 = [];

    $scope.atribuirUm = function(index, c) {
        $scope.clientes2.push(c);
        $scope.clientes.splice(index, 1);
    }

    $scope.limparUm = function(index, c2) {
        $scope.clientes2.splice(index, 1);
        $scope.clientes.push(c2);
    }

    /*
    * Trecho para validar o form ao submeter.
    */
    $scope.submitted = false;
    $scope.submitForm = function(form) {
        $scope.submitted = true;
        if (form.$valid) {
            $scope.cadastraCertificado();
        }
    };

    $scope.cadastraCertificado = function() {
        $http.post('/boxmlV2/cadastrocertificado/salvaCertificado', {
            urlCertificado : $scope.certificadoIncluirAlterar.urlCertificado,
            dataValidadeCertificado : $scope.certificadoIncluirAlterar.dataValidadeCertificado.toString(),
            senhaCertificado : $scope.certificadoIncluirAlterar.senhaCertificado
            //picklist???
            //certificado
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.sucesso();
        }, function(response) {
        });
    };
});
```

Mas não sei como passar o picklist que já funciona, pegando da base, os dados que preciso coletar é a lista do lado direito.

Como posso fazer isso?

Meu componente picklist:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Empresas:</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select multiple="multiple" class="multi-select" id="my_multi_select1" name="my_multi_select1[]">
            <option ng-repeat="c in clientes" value="{{c.idCliente}}" ng-click="atribuirUm($index, c)">{{c.razaoSocial}}</option>
            <option selected ng-repeat="c2 in clientes2" value="{{c2.idCliente}}" ng-click="limparUm($index, c2)">{{c2.razaoSocial}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obrigado, caso precisem de mais código, eu posto sem problemas.

---

Editado - botão salvar:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
        data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
        ng-click="submitForm(form)">
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Salvar
    </button>
</div>
```

Após aplicação da resposta fornecida, consigo receber o array OK, mas dá bad request 400 no envio, eu tirei o picklist como teste e consigo passar os outros atributos pro controller java com sucesso.
Estou recebendo no lado do Java, uma lista de String com o mesmo nome, deveria funcionar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como está o botão que você envia os demais dados para o `controller`?

Comment: Celsom, aquele botão do meio é falso, não é clicável. Quando clico no registro do lado esquerdo ele adiciona pro direito e vice versa. Vou postar como ficou meu js pra você ver... nao estou usando ng-model, sei que preciso pra passar...

Comment: Não não, não é isso.. O que eu quero saber é o seguinte, como está o seu botão "Salvar" para salvar todos os dados. O botão que chama a função "cadastraCertificado"

Comment: entendi, postei ele e a função sendo chamada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, primeiramente, recomendo que você remova a definição dos dados de dentro do $http, use uma variável ao invés disso, assim:

```
var dados = {
    urlCertificado :     $scope.certificadoIncluirAlterar.urlCertificado,
    dataValidadeCertificado : $scope.certificadoIncluirAlterar.dataValidadeCertificado.toString(),
    senhaCertificado : $scope.certificadoIncluirAlterar.senhaCertificado
};
```

Agora para definir a lista das empresas selecionadas você tem 2 modos para fazer isso:

- Passar como parâmetro pela botão que chama a função;
- Pegar diretamente do controller;

A segunda opção só funciona (e no seu caso é até mais simples) pois a manipulação das empresas é feita dentro do mesmo controller. Se fosse feita em outro local, não seria possível usar o segundo método (que é o que vou explicar).

O primeiro método seria assim:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
    ng-click="submitForm(form, clientes2)">
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Salvar
</button>
```

E no controller, ao receber a função, pegue ele também:

```
$scope.submitForm = function(form, clientes2) { //....
```

Como o seu já está dentro do controller, você pode pular essa etapa e referenciar ele diretamente através do `$scope.clientes2` e mesclar com a sua array de dados já existente (que exemplifiquei acima), assim:

```
dados['empresas'] = $scope.clientes2; //ou dados['clientes2'], fica a seu critério
```

Isso irá criar uma nested-array de dados que você pode apenas referenciar no $http e enviar, veja:

```
$scope.cadastraCertificado = function() {       
    $http.post('/boxmlV2/cadastrocertificado/salvaCertificado', dados)
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.sucesso();
        }, function(response) {         
    });
};
```

Comment: Celsom, obrigado novamente pelo empenho no auxilio, vou aplicar aqui lhe retorno...

Comment: Celsom, editei o post, legal eu recebi o array... só que na hora do envio da lista com 2 registros como teste, dá bad request, 400. Sabe porque? Estou com o mesmo nome de lista no lado do controller no java, deveria funcionar. Tem algo que preciso por na lista, como um .value ou algo do tipo especifico pra lista?

Comment: Bom, pode ser algumas coisas, inclusive não relacionada com o lado que está enviando os dados, ou seja, ou seu controller e o $http. Você está enviando so dados no formato json, então certifique-se de que o outro lado vá interpretar esse json corretamente. Outra coisa, os nomes dos campos. Certifique-se de não estar enviando nenhum campo a mais, nenhum campo a menos ou campos com erro de syntax. Você já verificou isso? Lembro que você queria enviar apenas alguns dados da empresa, confere?

Comment: Obrigado Celsom !

Comment: Não por isso! :)